# Whatchamacallit is short for what?

Tags: slang, abbreviations

Wikipedia says the slang "whatchamacallit" is short for *"what you might call it"*, but I remember hearing at some point that it's actually short for *"what'd your ma call it?"*

What is it short for?

Comment: *What you **may** call it*, not *might*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A number of dictionaries say that it comes from

> what you may call it

- [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whatchamacallit)
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whatchamacallit)
- [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=whatchamacallit&allowed_in_frame=0)

I've corrected the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whatchamacallit) page.